# How to query for rows that link to another row with a specific ID in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to query two different tables (`CALL_HISTORY` and `HUB_DIRECTORY`) to find all the call records that are made between a 'hub store' and a 'spoke store'. Each call has a `CallID` field and an entry is made with the id of the store that initiated the call and then a separate entry is made for each store that receives the call, and these all have the id of the store that receives them. So they all have the same `CallID` but the stores id (`DID`) is different for each.

The problem is that not every call is between a hub and its spoke, so I need to filter it out to find only these records.

[Sample Call Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hvWK.png)

```
RecordID | CallID  | DID   | CallDirection | StartTime 
--------------------------------------------------------
1563486  | 255429  | 492   | Initiated     | 1520870539
1563487  | 255429  | 849   | Received      | 1520870539
1563484  | 255430  | 1098  | Initiated     | 1520870562
1563485  | 255430  | 1098  | Received      | 1520870562
1563482  | 255431  | 307   | Initiated     | 1520870567
1563483  | 255431  | 1013  | Received      | 1520870567
1563506  | 255432  | 1108  | Initiated     | 1520870580
1563509  | 255432  | 1108  | Received      | 1520870580
```

Here you see a sample of the calls, the `CallID` group highlighted is between a hub and its spoke and the rest are not. The hubs and spokes are linked together in the `HUB_DIRECTORY` like so:

[HUB_DIRECTORY SAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrW6Z.png)

```
HubStore | HubDID | SpokeStore | SpokeDID
-----------------------------------------
4        | 37     | Store0004  | 37
4        | 37     | Store0522  | 470
7        | 1083   | Store0007  | 1083
7        | 1083   | Store1000  | 714
7        | 1083   | Store1055  | 759
12       | 38     | Store0012  | 38
12       | 38     | Store1063  | 758
13       | 45     | Store0013  | 45
13       | 45     | Store0337  | 296
13       | 45     | Store1012  | 724
```

The `HubDID` and `SpokeDID` fields are the same as the `DID` in `CALL_HISTORY`. So I'm looking to query for calls where the initiated call `DID` exists in the `HUB_DIRECTORY` table, as either a `HubDID` or a `SpokeDID`, and its `CallID` also has a record with a `DID` that matches with the appropriate hub/spoke.

My end goal would look like this:

```
HUB        | Spoke      | Initiated | Received
-----------------------------------------------
Store.0004 | Store.0522 |   304     |   723
```

I believe I will need to use a `UNION` to get the row with the hub or spoke but I am just unable to wrap my head around how this would be done.

Comment: please share your table structures

Comment: ok will do, but I also wanted to highlight the rows that are linked together

Comment: @Benjlaud1, that is not suficient, Add your tables into mysql fiddle

Comment: I'm having some troubles getting sqlfiddle to work but here is the table structures:  create TABLE HUB_DIRECTORY (
  HubStore int(11),
  HubDID int(11),
  SpokeStore varchar(25),
  SpokeDID int(11)
)
create TABLE CALL_DIRECTORY (
  RecordID int(4) primary key auto_increment,
  CallID int(4), 
  CallDirection enum('Received', 'Initiated'),
  StartTime int(4),
  DID int(4)
)

Comment: Try here , http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra here is what I got: http://rextester.com/ABLV40552

Comment: @Benjlaud1, Thanks for sharing data, your question is quite difficult to understand, could you please add some sample output based on input, As you mentioned in Question that **My end goal would look like this** data does not match with input.

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra sorry, still getting some input from my client as to their needs. basically What I'm looking to get should visually look like the example above, ordered by 'hub' and grouped by the 'spoke' and I need the count of calls that are 'Initiated' and 'Received'. let me know if you need any more info. We might be going a different direction if there is a faster better way to get this data.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer I'm not sure what you are referring too.  I've re-read the question and my comments several times over and don't see where I mention "urgent" or anything simular. Unless you mean I should have added urgent? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: "I need to get this done ASAP" (now edited out) is another way of saying that your work is urgent. The only purpose of mentioning this information is that you cannot complete that work until someone helps you. Thus, a volunteer should help you urgently. Bear in mind that, even if you did not intend for that inference to be made, we get several people here _every day_ expecting volunteers to respect a question author's deadlines, and we think it's healthy to reset these expectations.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry I thought I had put asap somewhere in there but then couldn't find it started questioning whether I had or not. I understand completely what your saying, and I promise you it was never my intention to abuse the kind people here who volunteer their support. I think I put it in there as an "I'll take anything I can get" but didn't like how it looked (being needy/ demanding) and removed it. Thanks for the heads up and I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: Looking at the sample call data in your image there is a call (255975) which is received by the same DID (508) multiple times. Do you intend to count each of those separately?

Comment: Yes, so i'm looking to to get a count of all calls made from the hub to one of its spokes, and all calls made from one of its spokes back to the hub.  Sorry, I'm trying my best to explain it but struggling to get my thoughts out...

Comment: @Benjlaud1 , How do I know that DID in Call is HubDID Or SpokerID ?

Comment: @Benjlaud1, As I can see in your input data (sqlFiddle) there are multiple CallID(255975) why it is so ? And in your above expected Result I can not see Initiated  (304) in sample input? Please This is cooked data then share the actual data people can understand your problem

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra if that DID is listed in the HUB_DIRECTORY as HubDID or SpokeDID. So I would join the tables on CALL_HISTORY.DID = HUB_DIRECTORY.HubDID or .SpokeDID.

Comment: @Benjlaud1, So What is understood is, you want data where Initiate and Receiver are from same DID for particular CallID right ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra looking for CallIDs that contain both a DID that is listed as a HubDID and it's corresponding SpokeDID according to the HUB_DIRECTORY table.  So I don't want any records that don't include both of these. And they want to see how many of these calls are initiated from the hub and how many were received by the hub.  That's why my sample output has 304 under initiated.  It's a made up count of records.  I've been using SUM(CALL_HISTORY.CallDirection="Initiated") to get the counts.

Comment: To further clarify,  I made up that sample output just for a visual. None of that data is real.

Comment: Thanks @Benjlaud1. For interest, the [revision history is here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49291756/revisions), and that link is available in all questions using the middle profile link, near the tags, marked as `edited`. This allows any reader to see the history of a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query will give you the results you want. It works on the limited sample data you provided.

```
select h1.hubstore, h1.hubdid,
       h1.spokestore, h1.spokedid,
       count(distinct if(c2.recordid is null or c1.did!=h1.hubdid, null, c1.recordid)) as initiated, 
       count(distinct if(c2.did!=h1.hubdid, null, c2.recordid)) as received     
from hub_directory h1 
left join (select * from call_history where calldirection='Initiated') c1 
    on c1.did=h1.hubdid or c1.did=h1.spokedid
left join (select * from call_history where calldirection='Received') c2 
    on c2.callid = c1.callid and c2.did=if(c1.did=h1.hubdid, h1.spokedid, h1.hubdid)
group by h1.hubstore, h1.spokestore
```

Based on the new sample data at your [fiddle](http://rextester.com/CATQPG68403), this query gives

```
hubstore    spokestore  initiated   received
355         Store0355   0           0
355         Store0362   0           0
355         Store0655   0           0
357         Store0233   1           2
357         Store0357   0           0
360         Store0360   0           0
360         Store0868   0           0
360         Store1091   0           0
363         Store0363   0           0
363         Store1462   1           0
363         Store1507   1           0
363         Store2507   0           0
```

Comment: This is SO close! just a couple things. It seems that it is counting the hub as an initiated call in the group even if the hub did not initiated the call. Then take newly added hubDID 319 which makes a call to two of its hubs but shows  that it initiated a call to the third spoke as well but then also says that the hub received a call from each of the two hubs that were in the call, which might just be a small tweak, I'll see if I can get it too. Here is an [updated fiddle](http://rextester.com/CATQPG68403) with your query and some additional data, I also added the DIDs for clarity.

Comment: You're right, it is double counting (as Initiated and Received) a call from a Hub to its Spoke (or vice versa). I think that is reasonably easy to resolve. Not sure about the strange initiated call to the third spoke. I've got a busy day today but will try and take a look at this at some point.

Comment: Well I really appreciate all your help. And I'll keep working on it too, and update when I get a solution.

Comment: As you initially described the problem, I'm not sure the double counting is incorrect. But perhaps you want the initiated column to only count calls initiated from a hub to a spoke, and the received column to only count calls initiated from a spoke to a hub?

Comment: My edit fixes the counting of initiated calls which were not received by all spokes on a hub.

Comment: AMAZING!!! I think this is it! The only thing I'm finding is if a Hub makes a call to it's self, it doesn't show. But that might not be a requirement to list those out. I will check into that but I really can not thank you enough for your time and input! Sorry for the confusion, it was really hard for to try describe all the finer points that we were looking for.

Comment: Glad to help - I've actually learnt a few things doing this so it was worth the time. I'm surprised it doesn't work when a hub calls itself, what does the data look like in that scenario?

Comment: Both records in a CallID would have the same DID.

Comment: Sure, here is an [updated sample](http://rextester.com/GFAHX19148). I changed the 200 in the first row with 317 which is the hubDID. I think they will be happy with what we have now so please don't stress over it.

Comment: Just as well you did that, it pointed out an error in the query when I looked at the new data. I'll edit the post with the correction.

Comment: This new query will also count calls from hub to hub, but it does show them as initiated AND received. I can't think of any way to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

As of now What I understand is like, You want to get data like how many call Received By Hub and How many call Initiated by Hub.

```
select 
a.hubDID, a.CallDirection, count(a.CallDirection) , 
hb.SpokeDID, ch.CallDirection, count(ch.CallDirection)   
from CALL_HISTORY ch inner join 
(
    select RecordID, CallID, DID, CallDirection, StartTime, h.HubStore , h.hubDID
    from CALL_HISTORY c inner join HUB_DIRECTORY h on (c.DID = h.HubDID)
) 
as a 
on ch.CallID = a.CallID 
and a.RecordID <> ch.RecordID
inner join HUB_DIRECTORY hb on hb.SpokeDID = ch.DID
```

Try here [Demo](http://rextester.com/YVOCS57423)

Grouped Data Query :

```
select 
a.hubDID, a.CallDirection, count(a.CallDirection) , 
count(hb.SpokeDID),
ch.CallDirection, count(ch.CallDirection)   
from CALL_HISTORY ch inner join 
(
    select distinct c.RecordID, c.CallID, c.DID, c.CallDirection, c.StartTime, c.DID  as hubDID
    from CALL_HISTORY c inner join HUB_DIRECTORY h on (c.DID = h.HubDID)
) 
as a 
on ch.CallID = a.CallID 
and a.RecordID <> ch.RecordID
inner join HUB_DIRECTORY hb on hb.SpokeDID = ch.DID
group by a.hubDID, a.CallDirection,

ch.CallDirection
;
```

Without Group Data Query:

```
select 
a.hubDID, a.CallDirection, count(a.CallDirection) , 
hb.SpokeDID,hb.SpokeDID,
ch.CallDirection, count(ch.CallDirection)   
from CALL_HISTORY ch inner join 
(
    select distinct c.RecordID, c.CallID, c.DID, c.CallDirection, c.StartTime, c.DID  as hubDID
    from CALL_HISTORY c inner join HUB_DIRECTORY h on (c.DID = h.HubDID)
) 
as a 
on ch.CallID = a.CallID 
and a.RecordID <> ch.RecordID
inner join HUB_DIRECTORY hb on hb.SpokeDID = ch.DID
group by a.hubDID, a.CallDirection,
hb.SpokeDID, 
ch.CallDirection
;
```

Comment: So that gets the records which contain a hub store.  Now I need to narrow those records down to ones where the call id also contains the corresponding spoke did. Basically I wonder if you could then do the same query doing SpokeDID instead of HubDID and then do like an inner join on the two sets where CallID is the same?

Comment: @Benjlaud1 I made query changes I hope this solve your problem

Comment: This is a huge step thank you so much. I added some additional call data to test things like other hubs and spokes and it seems to be grouping all of them by the first hub so there is only one row of results. [Updated Fiddle](http://rextester.com/OYL72834). Also noticed it seemed to be duplicating the results, showing 4 records instead of 2, which was a problem I was having in my testing too. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Benjlaud1, Hi I made two examples, (1) http://rextester.com/JDPF10138 This will show you grouped data,
(2) without group data http://rextester.com/NEVUL89999
I hope above two will solve your problem

Comment: Their site seems to be down, do you have the queries still?

Comment: @Benjlaud1, Hi I have added both queries in above answer

Comment: Thanks I'll look into them and see how it looks. Also, Where would you put the `WHERE` clause to filter on `StartTime`? Inside the Join?

Comment: You can put it before Group by clause